# A question regarding the derivation of the equation for the Planck black body radiation distribution

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

There is something that does not make sense to me regarding a derivation that I am reading of the Planck distribution for black body radiation emitted from a cavity. It treats the photons as particles, uses the 3D wave equation (from Maxwell's equation reasonable as photons are exclamations in the quantum field) applies a boundary condition of zero on the edges of the cavity treated as a box, all of which I am fine with. Photons are bosons, so that for any given wave vector $(px, py, pz)$ in the discrete space of momentum states there can be many photons,and each wave vector identifies one state; again fine with all this. What follows after this is where I have a problem. The derivation calculates the partition function as follows. It picks a single state $(px,py,pz)$, identified by one wave vector and "sums the states" corresponding to different numbers of photons in that single state as follows.

$$Z=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-nh\nu}$$

Where $\nu$ is the energy associated with that wave vector $(px,py,pz)$. To explain my problem, let me consider just two terms in this sum, with m > n, as shown below.

$$Z=...+ne^{-nh\nu}+me^{-mh\nu}+....$$

So the first "n" term corresponds to the case where there are n photons all in the considered momentum state $(px,py,pz)$. It says that there are n particles in this state $(px,py,pz)$. The $m$ term similarly says that there are m photons in the state $(px,py,pz)$ - a contradiction, because as as we just saw, there are $n$ terms in this state!

Where am I going wrong? What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summation is over all possible mutually exclusive states. The exponential factor is probability of that state.

Comment: Thanks.I kind of suspected that. This raises a subtly though. I am assuming the calc applies the Cannonical Ensemble with the individual momentum states treated as the boxes in the ensemble. But the Cannonical is a spatial averaging is it? We take a snapshot in time and all these states are actually present.  What you describe is I assume temporal averaging isnt it. Only one state, I.e., the n state is present at a simgle snapshot in time. I am guessing you can still do this, because the probability of any state is still the boltzman exponential. Is this right?

Comment: No, the summation in getting Z has nothing to do with spatial or temporal averaging. The summation is over all *possible* states of given harmonic oscillator with corresponding Boltzmann probability. Then, in derivation of the Planck function, there is summation over all harmonic oscillators. This second summation is summation over points in a Fourier space, not physical space.

Comment: I get that the mathematics is the sum over all states; it is the average number of photons in the state (px,py,pz). Let me put the question this way: when you compare the result of the Boltzmann sum with an experimental measurement, the answers agree. So all of the terms in this sum must be present in the experimental measurement. If we do not consider a time average, then the experiment is hypothetically a measurement at some precise time t. But at that would mean that all the terms in the sum are present in the experiment at time t. But that means there are n photons in state (px,py,pz),

Comment: But it also means that there are m terms in the state (px,py,pz) - a contradiction. Logically at that precise time t there are either n photons, or m photons in state (px,py,pz), but it cannot be both (over a small time interval yes, but at just one time no). Unless, are you saying that all the states exist in superposition at time t? If not, then how can all the terms in the sum be present in the experiment at a single point in time, t?

Comment: The sum that gives Z is not an experimentally measurable thing. The sum produces a function of temperature and volume that can be used to derive other things that can be compared to experiment, such as expected average radiation intensity at some frequency. Experiment that will measure such intensity does not happen at single instant of time, it takes some time to measure that. During that time, EM field in the system will change (fluctuate) and single mode intensity which is represented by $n$ in the sum can change its instantaneous value.

Comment: I think we are actually agreeing, but possibly talking cross purposes. I get the maths part. What I am pondering is the physics part. It is the question: when we do the experiment we get a result, then why does that result equal that Boltzmann sum. In the experiment, all the terms must be present, as the results agree with that sum. How does the experiment have all the terms in this sum? If you performed and extremely precise measurement at time t, you would measure a single instigate n(px,py,pz). This result would not agree with the above sum. If your performed another such experiment at time

Comment: at time t2, then you would measure another single state m(px,py,pz) which also wouldn't equal the above sum. But if you measure over a tiny interval from t to t +delta_t, with all the interactions and randomness ALL the states in the sum effectively occur (and are thus measured). So the experiment contains all the same terms as above, because any realistic measurement is over an interval long enough for all the states to occur. Thus the I think the experiment achieves the same sum over the measurement interval delta_t. Thus I think the EXPERIMENTAL result achieves the sum as a time average.

Comment: Yes, that is one way to think about what happens. Another way that I prefer is to think of this calculation as just a way to get expected average and abstain from any claims about what happens *in time*. The reason for this is measuring state of harmonic oscillator in time and verifying that it exists only in quantized states and jumps between different values of $n$ is hard to do and usually not done when measuring spectra of radiation.

Comment: In other words, your picture of what is happening is possible and plausible, but not easily seen in experiment and it is not necessary to understand and apply the above calculation.